# Dumb7Fill queen and rook attacks seem to jump over "ours" pieces

Tags: chess

I am trying to play with chess programming and currently program BitBoards. All is fine except for [Dumb7Fill](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Dumb7Fill) (unrolled loops) generating attacks that allow queen and rook jump over their pieces. Bellow are traces of execution. What am I doing wrong here? The code for *Attack is taken straight from the wiki page, which means that moves are extended into attacks by north, south, west and east shift. This is programmed in Java.

```
    long rooks = (One << index);
    long empty = ~rep.getOccupancy();
    long attacks = southAttack(rooks, empty)
            | northAttack(rooks, empty)
            | eastAttack(rooks, empty)
            | westAttack(rooks, empty);
    long actual = (attacks & rep.getCurrentPosition(getColor().inverse()));

ROOK ATTACKS w
rooks w 

. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
1 . . . . . . . 
n: 1

empty w 
. . . . . . . . 
1 . . . . . . . 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
. 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
. 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
n: 1fffefeff0100

theirs w 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
. 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
. . . . . . . . 
p . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
n: fffe000100000000

ours w 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
P . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
n: 100feff

attacks from Dumb7Fill w 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
1 . . . . . . . 
1 . . . . . . . 
1 . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . 1 . . . . . 
n: 101010004

actual attack w 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
1 . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
n: 100000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I misinterpreted the algorithms on the wiki page. The attacks include the shift by one and are attacks and not moves, as I have interpreted them. For moves one needs to use occluded fills.